# Can I run CAT6 between drywall and exterior block?

Tags: walls, cables, network

It is finally cold here in Florida, and I want to run CAT6 throughout my house from the attic. There are a few exterior walls that I want to run CAT6 down, and I am trying to figure out the best way to do it. My house has Coax run to some of these exterior walls, it runs externally and then is drilled through into the interior (I know about MoCA, but I would like to run CAT6 instead). I would like to avoid running the CAT6 externally if possible, so I went up into the attic to see how power lines are run in these exterior walls. It looks like there is a small gap between the drywall and the exterior block that the power cables run down (see pictures below).

[image]

[image]

My question is, with proper spacing between the power cables and the CAT6, is there anything preventing me from drilling a hole like the power cables have and running the CAT6 down the wall?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Low voltage cables/wires you can do what you feel like doing with them.  About the only code you need to worry about is about having low and high(120v) in the same junction box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On exterior walls, there are usually 1" x 2" furring strips nailed into the wall and then drywall attached to the furring strips. There's no problem notching/drilling the furring strip and running a cable through the hole and down in the cavity of the wall. If you plan it right, you can cut the hole for the junction box and drop a string with a metal washer on it from the attic and use a magnet to guide the washer into the box and then attach you cable to the string and pull it through. Interior wall usually use 2x4's between the drywall so there's more room to work with down the wall.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was hoping to hear. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Horiz0n When there's insulation in the walls, I've had luck running a metal tape measure down the wall. It's thin enough to fit between the wall and the insulation.